# "Convert Lead" is missing from Lead Layout page

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I've downloaded the latest version of SugarCRM Community Edition and am following this guide, [Adding Custom Modules to Lead Conversion](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/02KB/02Administration/100Studio_and_Module_Builder/Adding_Custom_Modules_to_Lead_Conversion/).

However the "Convert Lead" button is missing from that page. I've tried everything to work out why its not there and started looking at the source code. Does anyone know a reason why it might be missing? Is it only available on the paid for versions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, editing the 'Convert Lead' view thru Studio is only available in Pro and above. However, you can edit the metadata files behind the scenes to change the screen layout.